# Graphics Object in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, gdi+, system.drawing

I just started creating graphics in vb.net. 
I created a windows form and double clicked on it.
I then got a method which was **Form Load** method.
In this method i wrote the following code.

```
    Dim g As Graphics
    g = Me.CreateGraphics

    Dim pencolor As New Pen(Color.Red)
    g.DrawLine(pencolor, 10, 20, 100, 200)
```

I know that Graphics must be created in **Paint** event.
But i am trying to display them in the **Form Load** Event.
For some reason i don't see the output
What could possibly be the problem..??

Comment: If you know that you should do this in the `Paint` event, why don't you just do it? I see no reason why the code should be in the `Load` event.

Comment: My doubt is why is'nt the line being shown on the form when the form loads..?? I'm doing it so as to draw a line initially when the form loads

Comment: Because it is overriden by the `Paint` event. That's why you should perform every draw operation there.

Comment: A small note on style: never declare variables without initialising them. Your first two lines should be one line: `Dim g = Me.CreateGraphics()` (using `Option Infer On`). But that’s the wrong way anyway (`CreateGraphics()` is a horrible method that shouldn’t exist).

Comment: overrident by **Paint** event..?? 
i did not get it..
a little more explanation please..

Comment: Anything you draw in the Load event happens _before_ the form is displayed.  When the form is displayed, it is repainted and since you have no code in the Paint event, nothing is painted and what was previously there is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t use `CreateGraphics` – *ever*. I don’t think it actually has a legitimate use-case.

Your problem is that you paint something on the form but it’s over-written as soon as the next redrawing of the form is triggered because graphics you create that way are not persisted.

You essentially *have* to use the `Paint` event (or the `OnPaint` method) for drawing, there’s no way around this. If you want to trigger a redraw in `Form_Load` you can simply call `Me.Invalidate` (but I think that should be redundant).

Inside the [`OnPaint` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint.aspx) (or the `Paint` event), use the `Graphics` object provided in the parameters:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPaint(e) ' First, let the base class do its thing

    Dim g = e.Graphics

    Using p As New Pen(Color.Red)
        g.DrawLine(…)
    End Using
End Sub
```

(Notice that `Pen` is a disposable resource and as such you should wrap it in a `Using` block.)

Comment: Ok. Now i realize that i have no option but to use the **paint** event.
And thanks for pointing out to use object in the parameter list.

thanks for the detailed explanation.
Cleared my doubt.

Comment: You can also use one of the predefined pens, Pens.Red instead of creating your own.  If you do, _do not_ dispose it!

Comment: "Don’t use CreateGraphics – ever. I don’t think it actually has a legitimate use-case.". Of course it has. Rubber-banding in MouseMove is the first that springs to mind...

Comment: @DanByström No. You track the movement and rubberband positions in `MouseMove` and then trigger `OnPaint` by invalidating the control, and perform the actual painting there. Separation of concerns. That’s literally the situation described in my answer. I don’t know why `CreateGraphics` exists but I’d guess it was so VB6 programmers would have a quick’n’dirty method for directly porting code. That’s how *I* used it at the beginning, anyway. But then I learned to use the WinForms API properly.

Comment: I think the opposite. Cluttering up OnPaint with volatile drawing code that is only used during a drag operation is a violation of separation of concerns to me. Just the other day I implemented a magnifying glass in a WinForms project, and CreateGraphics made the code much cleaner than it would have been if I had just called Invalidate from MouseMove.

Comment: @Dan You don’t “clutter” it if you have a proper design. You have different `PaintJobs` that get queued and processed. Individual tasks create subclasses of `PaintJob`, initialise them and queue them. No clutter. The problem with `CreateGraphics`, as explained in the answer, is that it’s too volatile. You can’t do anything useful with it because there’s no reliable way of verifying that it’s actually drawn persistently rather than being immediately overwritten by some other paint event being fired. Its usage leads to display bugs, plain and simple.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim painted As Boolean = False

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)
        If Not painted Then
            painted = True
            e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Blue)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score -1):

I have extended this nice answer in VB.net (2010)  to deal with autosizing of the text in a DataGridView control.

First, modify the function to be:

```
Private Function MeasureTextWidth(ByVal c As Control, ByVal text As String) As Integer
    If (c Is DBNull.Value) Then
        Return -1
    Else
        Dim g As Graphics = c.CreateGraphics
        Return CInt(Math.Ceiling(g.MeasureString(text, c.Font).Width))
    End If
End Function
```

The next portion, in the software that calls this function is like this:

```
    With frm_Parameters_FITs
        .Show()
        With .DataGridView1
            .SuspendLayout()
            .DataSource = Nothing '  CRITICAL
            .AllowUserToAddRows = False
            .AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
            .AllowUserToResizeRows = False
            .AllowUserToOrderColumns = True
            .SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
            .ReadOnly = True
            .MultiSelect = False
            .RowHeadersVisible = False
            .Columns.Clear()
            .Rows.Clear()
            ' setup columns
            .Columns.Add("Item", "Item#")
            .Columns(0).Width = 11
            .Columns(0).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
            .Columns.Add("Parameter", "gHeaderTitle") ' (ColName, HeaderText)
            .Columns(1).Width = 25
            .Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .Columns(1).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
            .Columns.Add("ParamValue", "gHeaderInfo")
            .Columns(2).Width = 40
            .Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
            .Columns(2).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
            .Columns.Add("Comments", "gHeaderComment")
            .Columns(3).Width = 50
            .Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
            .Columns(3).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
            .Columns.Add("Comments", "Comments")
            .Columns(4).Width = 60
            .Columns(4).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
            .Columns(4).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
            .ResumeLayout(True)
        End With
        'Then you can add the data in rows to the cells of the DataGridView:
        Dim piIndex As Integer ' this is a row pointer
        Dim ColTextWidth(5) As Integer
        Dim TextToMeasure As String
        Dim IntTextWidthPixels As Integer

        With .DataGridView1
            For i As Integer = 1 To Globals.giHeaderLines
                .Rows.Add() ' increases the rows.count...the last index is (rows.count-1)
                piIndex = .Rows.Count - 1  ' pointer to the last row just added
                .Rows(piIndex).Cells(0).Value = i.ToString ' puts this text into the col 0 cell

                .Rows(piIndex).Cells(0).Style.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
                .Rows(piIndex).Cells(1).Value = gHeaderTitle(i)
                .Rows(piIndex).Cells(2).Value = gHeaderInfo(i)
                .Rows(piIndex).Cells(3).Value = gHeaderComment(i)
                .Rows(piIndex).Cells(4).Value = gHeaderComment(i)
                ' now determine the correct col width
                For j As Integer = 0 To 4
                    Try
                        TextToMeasure = .Rows(piIndex).Cells(j).Value
                        IntTextWidthPixels = MeasureTextWidth(frm_Parameters_FITs.DataGridView1, TextToMeasure)

                        If IntTextWidthPixels > ColTextWidth(j) Then
                            ColTextWidth(j) = IntTextWidthPixels
                        End If
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Debug.Print("Error here in Class_FileIO_FITs. PutDataIntoHeaderDataGrid")
                    End Try
                Next j
            Next i
            ' now reset the cols to the correct width
            For j As Integer = 0 To 4
                .Columns(j).Width = ColTextWidth(j)
            Next j
        End With
        'make sure the row we added is visible
        .DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = piIndex
        .DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
        .DataGridView1.Rows(piIndex).Selected = True
        .Refresh()
    End With
```

This works fine to provide the DataGridView control with correctly wide columns.

Comment: What answer did you actually extend? I can't tell, and "above" is, or soon will be, useless: answers are sorted by votes by default, which can change. Add a link.

Comment: The contribution extends the c# code into VB.net code.  It shows that the CreateGraphics is usable, and makes the text width metric simple.

Comment: There are no answers in this question with C# code, so whatever answer you were extending is not here. **Please** link to the actual answer this is based on.